# Interview Puzzle: How to find all "bad" worker histories?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, combinatorics

This is an interview question. Suppose we represent working histories of workers as strings. Each string consists of `N` characters;  each character is one of {`A` -- "absence", `L` -- "late", and `O` -- "ok"). The system raises alarm if either there are two "absences" or three subsequent "late". For example: `AOOAO` -- raises alarm, `ALLOL` -- does not.

Write a function (in Java) to generate all strings of size `N`, which raise alarm.

I would propose to loop over all possible "working history" strings (it is pretty obvious how to generate them) and filter required strings with a regular expression.

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: There is actually a separate stack exchange for "solve this problem" questions where you may find more enthusiastic contributors: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: do you really mean subsequent or do you mean consecutive?

Comment: @SantoshK I mean that `OLLOL` does not raise alarm but `OLLLO` does.

Comment: I'd leave the interview. Being late 3 days in a row shouldn't raise an alarm.

Comment: So if, whenever you would be late for the third time, you just skip the entire workday, filing in one absence; then be late two more days, ... that's a great job policy, appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks @Marko Topolnik obv. I was wrong in a sense. With your added comment I do feel I don't want to work for the (imaginary) company anyways.

Answer (score 4):

This would be a smart approach that doesn't check anything, but generates only the correct cases directly:

1. Make all possible variations with N-2 days (that's 3^(N-2) combinations). For every variation so obtained make N-1 final strings by splicing in "AA" at every possible position (plus simply appending at the end, that's why it's N-1).
2. Repeat with N-3 days and splicing in "LLL".
3. You're all done.

## EDIT

Now I see the absences need not be consecutive. That changes the solution just a bit:  in the first case you'll splice in two "A"s independently, first one and then the other into the resulting string.

## EDIT 2

There's a nicely symmetrical additional check that avoids duplicates when splicing in. In both steps check the char to the left of your insertion point. In step 1, if it's an A, stop the current splicing-in iteration (this also controls the splicing-in of the second A). In step 2, if it's an L, go to the next insertion point (skip the current insertion point).

Comment: You will generate the result "AALLL" multiple times.

Comment: @btilly Yes, there will be duplicates. It will generate only the correct cases, though (as stated).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  I like your answer, especially for an interview. Can't say it performs any better than my solution. It seems that the combination is the most costly part of the solution (assuming no regex is involved).

Comment: Oh, this is the elegance I couldn't find. I wonder if it is actually easier and faster to code than my solution, and if it executes faster or not.

Comment: I think there is a tiny error though, I think you need to check the first generated strings, since you can splice in any 2 characters at any place in a string that is already raising an alarm at length N-2.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik There will be an average of `O(n*n)` duplicates generated per unique output you were looking for.  This is not a small amount of excess.

Comment: @esej It is perfectly fine if I start with a string that is already causing an alarm. There is no stipulation that a string must contain **exactly one** reason for alarm. If I did what you say, I would actually miss a whole lot of required strings.

Comment: @btilly In step 1. you can reject all strings containing "LLL". That eliminates all strings generated in step 2.

Comment: Duplicates are harder than you think.  Most are due to having more than 2 As.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution similar to the brute force except with some optimization. The idea is to create a combination of all possible sequences (no additional cost since the alarm string has to be returned). Then keep track of the alarm conditions (absolutely no regex) so that only the current character needs to be checked (see #2). Once a substring has raised the alarm, lets say by position i, the function can continue creating the combination for the n-i characters without checking the alarm conditions.

1. Create a char array, size N, and a function that will compute the combination (`3^N`).
2. Create a variable `numLate`, which will keep track of the consecutive 'L' in the series so far and a variable `numAbsences` which will keep track of the number of 'A' in the series so far.
3. At each step during the combination, check the following:

   - If a match has already been found (`match == true`) continue.
   - Otherwise:

     - Check if the current character is an 'A', if so increment `numAbsences`. If `numAbsences > 1`, set `match = true`. Continue.
     - If the current character is 'L' increment `numLate`, otherwise set `numLate = 0`. If `numLate > 2`, set `match = true`. Continue.

During the combination, when the Nth character is being set, if `match==true` return the current string. Otherwise, skip, it is not a match. Additional (minor) optimizations can be made by not checking for absences if you're on the last character and there have been 0 absences so far. Or on last 2 characters of combination and there has been 0 late days.

Edit: I'm posting a recursive (groovy) solution. For example, `Test.combination(0, new char[10], false, 0, 0);` returns 55513 combinations, not sure if it's correct though.

```
class Test{
    public static final char[] rep = ['O', 'A', 'L'];

    public static void combination(int index, char[] arr, boolean match, int numLate, int numAbsence){
        if(index==arr.length){
            if(match)
                println arr;
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<rep.length;i++){
            arr[index] = rep[i];
            if(!match){
                boolean tempMatch = match;
                int tempNumLate = numLate;
                int tempNumAbsence = numAbsence;
                switch(arr[index]){
                    case 'L': tempNumLate++; break;
                    case 'A': tempNumAbsence++; tempNumLate=0; break;
                    default: tempNumLate = 0; break;
                }
                if(tempNumLate > 2)
                    tempMatch = true;
                if(tempNumAbsence > 1)
                    tempMatch = true;

                combination(index+1, arr, tempMatch, tempNumLate, tempNumAbsence);
            }else{
                combination(index+1, arr, match, numLate, numAbsence);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is indeed the correct number of combinations.

Answer (score 1):

For something completely different, here is an approach that generates exactly the needed strings and nothing else.  View it as a state machine, and make each state a function.  Very verbose but straightforward.  (If you were doing a lot of this you could easily arrange to auto-generate this code.)

Because we were asked for Java, here is Java.  (I also wrote the same code in Perl.  I just did `.=` and `chop` for a string instead of `StringBuilder` and it ran 3x faster than the Java version.  Odd.)

```
import java.io.*;

public class ListAllAlarmedStrings {
    static StringBuilder builder;
    static int length;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        length = 5;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                length = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Argument" + " must be an integer");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        builder = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
          builder.append("O");
        stateA(0, 'A');
        stateL(0, 'L');
        stateNone(0, 'O');
    }

    static void stateNone (int pos, char chr) {
        if (length < pos + 3)
            return;
        builder.setCharAt(pos, chr);
        //System.out.println("stateNone " + pos + " " +builder.toString());
        stateA(pos + 1, 'A');
        stateL(pos + 1, 'L');
        stateNone(pos + 1, 'O');
    }

    static void stateL (int pos, char chr) {
        if (length < pos + 3)
            return;
        builder.setCharAt(pos, chr);
        //System.out.println("stateL " + pos + " " +builder.toString());
        stateA(pos + 1, 'A');
        stateLL(pos + 1, 'L');
        stateNone(pos + 1, 'O');
    }

    static void stateLL (int pos, char chr) {
        if (length < pos + 2)
            return;
        builder.setCharAt(pos, chr);
        //System.out.println("stateLL " + pos + " " +builder.toString());
        stateA(pos + 1, 'A');
        stateAlarmed(pos + 1, 'L');
        stateNone(pos + 1, 'O');
    }

    static void stateA (int pos, char chr) {
        if (length < pos + 2)
            return;
        builder.setCharAt(pos, chr);
        //System.out.println("stateA " + pos + " " +builder.toString());
        stateAlarmed(pos + 1, 'A');
        stateAL(pos + 1, 'L');
        stateA(pos + 1, 'O');
    }

    static void stateAL (int pos, char chr) {
        if (length < pos + 2)
            return;
        builder.setCharAt(pos, chr);
        //System.out.println("stateAL " + pos + " " +builder.toString());
        stateAlarmed(pos + 1, 'A');
        stateALL(pos + 1, 'L');
        stateA(pos + 1, 'O');
    }

    static void stateALL (int pos, char chr) {
        if (length < pos + 2)
            return;
        builder.setCharAt(pos, chr);
        //System.out.println("stateALL " + pos + " " +builder.toString());
        stateAlarmed(pos + 1, 'A');
        stateAlarmed(pos + 1, 'L');
        stateA(pos + 1, 'O');
    }

    static void stateAlarmed (int pos, char chr) {
        if (length <= pos)
            return;
        if (length == pos + 1) {
            builder.setCharAt(pos, chr);
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
            return;
        }
        builder.setCharAt(pos, chr);
        stateAlarmed(pos + 1, 'A');
        stateAlarmed(pos + 1, 'L');
        stateAlarmed(pos + 1, 'O');
    }
}
```